# Connect SWI-Prolog with HTML5. Is that possible?

Tags: html, swi-prolog

Is there any guide, tool or something else to connect SWI-Prolog with HTML5 to create a web interface?

Comment: Put your Prolog functionality into a library with a Foreign Function Interface, and call it with some orthodox web framework.  Use any framework you like... Ruby on Rails, ASP.NET MVC, Node.JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SWI-Prolog can be run as a web service. See:

http://www.swi-prolog.org/howto/http/

There's also a tutorial on "Creating Web Applications in SWI-Prolog" at:

http://www.pathwayslms.com/swipltuts/html/index.html